# What causes sql server to generate a new plan for a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, execution-plan

We've ran into an issue in production a couple of times now where it looks like a stored procedure gets a new, bad plan and starts causing havoc.  Unfortunately, we weren't able to capture the plan before and after to see what the bad plan looked like before we did a dbcc freeproccache, we also don't have query store set up.

My question is, what all can cause sql server to generate a new plan for a stored procedure?  Especially for an sp that is ran all of the time.  Some of the ones I know are:

- dbcc freeproccache
- rebooting the server
- option recompile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For SQL 2016 here is the list why 'statement_recompile_cause' can happen.

- Schema changed
- Statistics changed
- Deferred compile
- Set option change
- Temp table changed
- Remote rowset changed
- For browse permissions changed
- Query notification environment changed
- PartitionView changed
- Cursor options changed
- Option (recompile) requested
- Parameterized plan flushed
- Test plan linearization
- Plan affecting database version changed
- Query Store plan forcing policy changed
- Query Store plan forcing failed
- Query Store missing the plan

You can get the same list for any other versions that support Extended Event tracing.

```
 Select 
  [name],
  map_key,
  map_value
FROM sys.dm_xe_map_values 
WHERE [name] ='statement_recompile_cause'
```

Few good references:

1. A [good article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5308/understanding-sql-server-recompilations/) to read by Bhavesh Patel
2. Another [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054100/what-factors-can-cause-stored-procedure-recompilation-on-sql-server) in StackOverflow.
3. [When does a Stored Procedure recompile?(Sql Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594344/when-does-a-stored-procedure-recompilesql-server)

Comment: Alter proc ,dynamic sql without sp_execute